# Can I encode binary JS data - including uIntArrays and ArrayBuffers - to a string format in a single step?

Tags: javascript, serialization

> *Similar to [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64) however I'm asking about JS datatypes specifically (like Uint8Array) and don't have a requirement to use JSON.*

I have a JS `Object` with many nested values including values of type `Uint8Array` and `ArrayBuffer` that I need to send as an encoded string.

I know I can convert individual fields to strings and then manually decode each specific field on the other end.

That's the approach I'm currently taking - through code like:

```js
export const uInt8ArrayToString = (uInt8Array: Uint8Array) => {
  const string: string = utf8Decoder.decode(uInt8Array);
  return string;
};

export const arrayBufferToString = (buffer: ArrayBuffer): string => {
  return utf8Decoder.decode(new Uint8Array(buffer));
};
```

And for decoding:

```js
export const stringToUint8Array = (string: string) => {
  const uint8Array: Uint8Array = utf8Encoder.encode(string);
  return uint8Array;
};

export const stringToArrayBuffer = (string: string) => {
  const uint8Array: Uint8Array = utf8Encoder.encode(string);
  const arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer = uInt8ArrayToArrayBuffer(uint8Array);
  return arrayBuffer;
};
```

However this seems somewhat inefficient, as I have to note the data type used by each field and encode/decode specific fields on end/

**Can I encode binary JS data - including uIntArrays and ArrayBuffers - to a string format in a single step?**

Comment: Look into JSON.stringify and parse. In both you can add a replacer and reviver function where you can do custom stringification/parsing based on type of object. Details in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#using_a_function_as_replacer and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_reviver_when_paired_with_the_replacer_of_json.stringify

Comment: Thanks @PeterThoeny! I did consider this but rather than have a bunch of my own functions, considered that there would be other JS user that needed to store ArrayBuffers and uInt8Arrays etc. and eventually found esserializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question to help others**

Looking at other questions (which were mainly focused on [high-level types like
class instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74335130/deserializing-json-to-a-class-with-methods-in-typescript/74587052#74587052) rather than uIntArrays and ArrayBuffers) I was able to find [esserializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esserializer)

Run with `npx esrun runme.js`:

```
import ESSerializer from "esserializer";
import { log } from "console";

const foo = {
  bar: new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3]),
  baz: new ArrayBuffer([4, 5, 6]),
};

const serialized = ESSerializer.serialize(foo);

const deserialized = ESSerializer.deserialize(serialized);

log(deserialized);
```

Will return:

```
{
  bar: Uint8Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  baz: ArrayBuffer { [Uint8Contents]: <>, byteLength: 0 }
}
```